# Solving for vector elements in a function to which the vectors are not passed explicitly

Tags: equation-solving, functions, vector

I want to define a function which takes in two integers (indicating the lengths of 2 vectors), and solves a simple set of expressions at a set of points to find all the values in both the vectors.

so far I have managed to successfully create a function which does exactly what I say above, except that rather than taking two integers as arguments, it takes the two vectors itself. Forgive me for the length of this next code fragment:

```
solution[svec_, nvec_] := 
  NSolve[
   Table[
     approx[svec, nvec, -Cos[n*Pi/(Length[nvec] + Length[svec])]] == 
       exact[-Cos[n*Pi/(Length[nvec] + Length[svec])]],
     {n, 1, Length[nvec] + Length[svec]}],
   Join[svec, nvec]];
```

The

```
-Cos[n*Pi/(Length[nvec] + Length[svec])
```

part is just a set of points. All of the above works fine.

My attempt to change it so that it takes in just integers was to do the following:

STEP ONE: create a function which takes an integer, gives a vector of length integer:

```
nvec[Q_] := Table[Unique["n"], {Q}];
svec[M_] := Table[Unique["s"], {M}];
```

STEP TWO: replace all of the `svec`s and `nvec`s in the previous code fragment with `nvec[Q]` and `svec[M]`. (could also get rid of Lengths obviously):

```
solution[Q_, M_] := 
  NSolve[
    Table[
      approx[svec[M], nvec[Q], -Cos[n*Pi/(Q + M)]] == exact[-Cos[n*Pi/(Q + M)]],
      {n, 1, M + Q}],
    Join[svec[M], nvec[Q]]];
```

STEP THREE: Call the function

```
sol = solution[10, 20]
```

For some reason, this doesn't work. I never get an error; it just never finishes evaluating. Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Does it work if you replace your `solution[Q_,M_]` by `solution2[Q_, M_] := 
 With[{sv = svec[M], nv = nvec[Q]},  NSolve[Table[ approx[sv, nv, -Cos[n*Pi/(Q + M)]] ==  exact[-Cos[n*Pi/(Q + M)]], {n, 1, M + Q}], Join[sv, nv]]]`?

Comment: yes! Thank you very much, i'll have to look up why that works :)

Comment: btw, using this method is there a simple way to get out the vectors being solved?

for example I used to use `sing = 1.0*svec /. sol`